# Batch file to delete specific folders

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, directory

I need a batch file that will recursively remove all directories with a certain filename. This is what I have so far and its not working.

```
FOR /D /r %%G IN ("*.svn") DO DEL %%G
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow I recently just did something exactly like this:

**edit**

`FOR /F %%C IN ('dir *.svn /s /b') DO DEL %%~C\*.*`

`FOR /D %%C IN ('dir *.svn /s /b') DO RMDIR %%~C`

You probalby need to pass some parameters to `del` to allow it to delete without asking yes/no

Alternatively just do `svn export` to checkout code from the repository without those pesky .svn directories.

Comment: this is not working. The folders im trying to delete are named .svn and are hidden.

Comment: Well you could just do `svn export`. That will export your repository without all the .svn directories.

Comment: You pretty much got it. Just needed a few tweaks and like you said del needed some params to allow delete. Here's the final command.

FOR /F %%C IN ('dir *.svn /s /b /a:d') DO RMDIR %%C /s /q

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to work with Powershell you can use this snippet:

```
get-childitem . -include .svn -force -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item -force $_.fullname}
```

It's taken from [here](http://www.williambharding.com/blog/technology/delete-dos-directories-recursively/). Actually if you can use Powershell just forget DOS :)

By the way the `dir` command has a `/s` to act recursively (like `-r/-R` for unix like shells)